# Select more than one item by clicking in a datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I use my datagrid to select an item to generate a report. But now I need to be able to select more than one item when holding down the CTRL key. How can I accomplish this

```
private void dgvPrint_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {        
  this.Clear_Print();

  if (e.RowIndex < 0)
    return;
    this.mEmpId = Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvPrint.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["empid_Print"].FormattedValue);
    this.lblEmpPrint.Text = this.dgvPrint.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Empname_Print"].FormattedValue.ToString();

    this.btnPrint.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: He does not need to place there the `{}` brackets if your task of the `if` definition is a one liner. It´s a short form basically. Wow deleting your own comment is a very clever idea, makes us look like fools.

Comment: Do you use WinForm or WPF?

Comment: @ifconfig thanks for noticing but you can have an if statement without the curly braces

Comment: @L.Guthardt am using WinForms

Comment: In the properties multiselect must be set to true, then you can do a foreach loop on the datagrid selected rows and execute the 'CellClick' function

Comment: @MichaelTralala thanks for the suggestion,let me try that

Comment: So since atleast VS 2015, multiselect is already set to true automatically. You can select mutilple cells by holding down Ctrl and clicking on the cell by default.

Comment: @karcs did it work? If so please accept answer, if not please tell why not

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set properties
        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

        // Create fictional rows since i dont have your datasource
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "col1");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col2", "col2");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col3", "col3");

        int loop = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dgr = new DataGridViewRow();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgr);
        }
    }

    // After button click (or any other event for that matter)
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get all selected rows
        foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            // execute row
            cellClickFunction(dgvr);
        }
    }

    // Pass selected row to cellClickFunction (this is NOT the click event)
    private void cellClickFunction(DataGridViewRow dgvr)
    {
        // Your code
        this.Clear_Print();

        this.mEmpId = Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvr.Cells["empid_Print"].FormattedValue);
        this.lblEmpPrint.Text = this.dgvPrint.dgvr["Empname_Print"].FormattedValue.ToString();

        this.btnPrint.Enabled = true;
    }
```